# Saving file as .pem from powershell 5.1 with encoding as utf8noBOM and reading it with openssl throws error

Tags: json, powershell, api, openssl, byte-order-mark

I'm trying to upload the .pem file to an API using powershell, we have to convert it to JSON format and then post it. Well, this works fine by using the below snippet

```
$t = Get-Content -Delimiter "`n" -Path 'xxxxxx.pem'
$a = [pscustomobject]@{"certificate" = "$($t)" 
                       "description" = "" 
                       "extension" = ".pem"}
$body = $a | convertto-json
$web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers -Body $body -Method POST
```

While retrieving, i'm using the below snippet

```
$web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers
$temp = $web.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$cert = $temp.data.certificate
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("*****.pem", $cert, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
```

Then I pass the file created using the above snippet to openssl, as follows

```
openssl.exe x509 -in "*****.pem" -checkend 129600
```

which is throwing me the following error,

```
openssl.exe : unable to load certificate
At line:1 char:1
+ openssl.exe x509 -in "******.pem" -checkend 129600
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (unable to load certificate:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

14660:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

I'm baffled here, dont know what did i get wrong.

Cause both files, the orginal .pem file and the one created from PS are utf-8 encoded and couldn't see any BOM chars in notepad++.

Comment: What happens if you read in the PEM using `Get-Content -Raw` instead of using the `-Delimiter` argument? My suspicion is that some strangeness is going on because the line endings are likely getting mucked with.

Comment: i had to use the delimiter to sustain the \n in the double quotes, if not the format will be lost

Comment: But does openssl recognize the PEM when you read the file using the `-Raw` argument?

Comment: Does [this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/317038) answer your question?

Comment: @theo I was ultimately thinking this is the problem, the way the file is being rewritten with windows line endings

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Openssl does recognize it even when i use `-raw`

Comment: @Theo i had already been to that page before asking the question. I'm saving the file in BOM format, so thats not the problem here

Comment: i found out that the error was due to the white space at the begining of everyline in the pem file which i'm saving.

Comment: In the first code block, i'm trying while i'm trying to save the pem content into certificate property of custom object, only the very line is written with no leading space and rest all the line have an extra leading space. Any ideas why?